# Mule Logging slf4j

Tags: log4j, mule, slf4j, log4j2

The Mule 3.3.x documentation here ( http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Configuring+Logging ) says that Mule uses slf4j as a facade for logging. Based on that, I expected to be able to delete log4j-1.2.16.jar from mule\lib\boot and add in log4j-api-2.0-beta7, log4j-core-2.0-beta7, log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-beta7 to take advantage of log4j 2.0.

When I do this, I get an exception that org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap cannot be found.

Looking further, I do not find slf4j-api.jar anywhere in the Mule installation, a library I thought required to use slf4j.

Is the Mule documentation incorrect or is there something else I need to do?

Here's the truncated stacktrace from Mule.  For some reason, uncommenting the "-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true" option in wrapper.conf isn't giving me full stacktraces.

```
Error in WrapperListener.start callback.  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap
    at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.<init>(Hierarchy.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.<init>(ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.java:44)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.<clinit>(MuleContainer.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:54)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.or.RendererMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 11 more
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also slf4j is used as a facade, the actual logging is done by log4j appenders. But still I don't get why it depends on a particular class in log4j.

Comment: I'll add the stacktrace it into the message above.  The thing is, given that I don't see either slf4j-api.jar (the SLF library) or slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar (the log4j binding library) in the Mule installation, I'm wondering if SLF is even being used.  If not...if it's going directly against log4j, then the error makes sense.

Comment: Open `mule-module-logging-3.3.1.jar`: you'll see embedded SLF4J classes.

Comment: Hmmm, since that library has other classes in it (presumably required by Mule for logging) and since SLF wants only one binding library present, I don't understand how Mule's use of SLF is designed to allow substitution of other logging mechanisms...which I thought was one of the main points of SLF.  Unless they're expecting me to edit a distributed library, which doesn't appeal.